# Influx: doing math the same fields in different groups

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

I have InfluxDB measurement currently set up with following "schema":

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| ts | cost(field) | type(tag) |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | 10          | 'a'       |
|  1 | 20          | 'b'       |
|  2 | 12          | 'a'       |
|  2 | 18          | 'b'       |
|  2 | 22          | 'c'       |
+------------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to write a query that will group my table by timestamp and get a delta between field values of two different tags. If I want to get delta between tag 'a' and tag 'b', it will give me following result (please not that I ignore tag 'c'):

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| ts | type(tag) | delta_cost |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 'a'       | 10         |
|  2 | 'b'       |  6         |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Is it something Influx can do or am I using the wrong tool?

Comment: From your deltas, it looks like you're grouping by time, not by "type" tag. Doublecheck what exactly you're asking for, please.

Comment: @YuriG thanks for pointing it out, I indeed try to group by timestamp, and get a delta between field values of two different tags for that timestamp group. I updated question details, please let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just managed to answer my own question. While one of the obvious ways would be performing self-join, Influx does not support joins anymore. We can, however, use nested selects in a following format:

```
SELECT MEAN(cost_a) - MEAN(cost_b) as delta_cost
FROM
    (SELECT cost as cost_a, tag, tablename where tag='a'),
    (SELECT cost as cost_b, tag, tablename where tag='b')
GROUP BY time(60s)
```

Since I am getting my data every 60 seconds anyway, and I have a guarantee of just one point per tag per 60 seconds, I can use `GROUP BY` and take `MEAN` without any problems

Comment: Sorry to kind of disappoint you, but you don't have such a guarantee, at least, this way. Just consider there could be a jitter at the gatherer/shipper side... However, it's pretty easy to make this guarantee solid: the LAST(), or other selector function.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53711110/make-cumulative-function-that-resets-daily/57433286#57433286) :)