# Make InfluxDB/Grafana cumulative function that resets daily (sawtooth graph)

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm logging energy usage data as a counter, which I would like to display as cumulative graphs that reset daily, as similarly [asked here](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-cumulative-sum-for-kwh-that-resets-daily/5518).

I can generate the cumulative value as follows:

```
SELECT mean("value") \
  FROM "energy" \
  WHERE $timeFilter \
  GROUP BY time($__interval)
```

and the daily value as well:

```
SELECT max("value") \
  FROM "energy" \
  WHERE $timeFilter \
  GROUP BY time(1d)
```

but I cannot subtract this or get this in one query, because the GROUP BY times are different.

(How) is this possible in influxdb? I've looked at INTEGRATE() but this haven't found a way to make this working.

The data looks like this (example limited to 1 day):

```
time                 value
----                 ----
2018-12-10T17:00:00Z 7
2018-12-10T18:00:00Z 9
2018-12-10T19:00:00Z 10
2018-12-10T20:00:00Z 11
2018-12-10T21:00:00Z 13
2018-12-10T22:00:00Z 14
2018-12-10T23:00:00Z 15
2018-12-11T00:00:00Z 16
2018-12-11T01:00:00Z 17
2018-12-11T02:00:00Z 20
2018-12-11T03:00:00Z 24
2018-12-11T04:00:00Z 25
2018-12-11T05:00:00Z 26
2018-12-11T06:00:00Z 27
2018-12-11T07:00:00Z 28
2018-12-11T08:00:00Z 29
2018-12-11T09:00:00Z 31
2018-12-11T10:00:00Z 32
2018-12-11T11:00:00Z 33
2018-12-11T12:00:00Z 34
2018-12-11T13:00:00Z 35
2018-12-11T14:00:00Z 36
2018-12-11T15:00:00Z 37
2018-12-11T16:00:00Z 38
2018-12-11T17:00:00Z 39
```

I can plot the following:
[image: Current state]

But I want something like:
[image: Desired output]

Comment: Did you try CUMULATIVE_SUM() function? https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#cumulative-sum

Comment: how your data points look like? do you collect your "value" as a cumulative counter through the day, or is that any kind of "immediate" value (over some time delta)?

Comment: @YuriG: the data is already cumulative, see example data I just added, but that does not matter for my question as I can convert between the two with `DERIVATIVE()` and `CUMULATIVE_SUM()`.

Comment: @JanGaraj: yes, but how would this reset daily to get sawtooth-like graphs?

Comment: @Tim probably GROUP BY time(1d)

Comment: Cumulative sum works on gauge value, if you apply it to a counter - you've end up with pile of useless crap.

Comment: @Tim, as soon as your value is already cumulative - you need nothing to show it properly, except for some type of aggregation or selection upon your time deltas you choose four your graph. LAST() would play good enough there. What you need to mend - is the way you send it: reset it to zero at some point (which is 12am, in your case). Right there, where you batch & send it to Influx. That's it.

Comment: @YuriG: I know my data is cumulative, but I want to have it reset to zero daily, preferably without having to change the data itself. So far no solution yet I'm afraid

Comment: But for that you just need to zero your counter at the spot you gather & send it! Or you can send the delta over time value (non-cumulative, obviously) - then CUMULATIVE_SUM() would work perfectly.

Comment: @YuriG I don't want to change my input data. Is there any way I can do it using  influxdb/grafana functions?

Comment: Well... it's pretty easy to turn cumulative values into deltas (with DIFFERENCE()). Although, here's the problem: the CUMULATIVE_SUM() doesn't allow grouping by time to be used without nested aggregation function. The only way I observe now is to reshape your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439122/influx-doing-math-the-same-fields-in-different-groups), it's quite simple in the end:

```
SELECT kaifa-kaifa_fill as Energy FROM
  (SELECT first(kaifa) as kaifa_fill from energyv2 WHERE $timeFilter group by time(1d) TZ('Europe/Amsterdam')),
  (SELECT first(kaifa) as kaifa from energyv2 WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval))
fill(previous)
```

Note the fill(previous) is required to ensure kaifa_fill and kaifa overlap.

Example data:

```
time                 kaifa     kaifa_fill kaifa_kaifa_fill
----                 -----     ---------- ----------------
2019-08-03T00:00:00Z 179688195 179688195  0
2019-08-03T01:00:00Z 179746833 179688195  58638
2019-08-03T02:00:00Z 179803148 179688195  114953
2019-08-03T03:00:00Z 179859464 179688195  171269
2019-08-03T04:00:00Z 179914038 179688195  225843
2019-08-03T05:00:00Z 179967450 179688195  279255
2019-08-03T06:00:00Z 179905910 179688195  217715
2019-08-03T07:00:00Z 179847272 179688195  159077
2019-08-03T08:00:00Z 179698065 179688195  9870
2019-08-03T09:00:00Z 179378170 179688195  -310025
2019-08-03T10:00:00Z 179341013 179688195  -347182
2019-08-03T11:00:00Z 179126201 179688195  -561994
2019-08-03T12:00:00Z 179039116 179688195  -649079
2019-08-03T13:00:00Z 178935193 179688195  -753002
2019-08-03T14:00:00Z 178687870 179688195  -1000326
2019-08-03T15:00:00Z 178517762 179688195  -1170433
2019-08-03T16:00:00Z 178409776 179688195  -1278420
2019-08-03T17:00:00Z 178376102 179688195  -1312093
2019-08-03T18:00:00Z 178388875 179688195  -1299320
2019-08-03T19:00:00Z 178780181 179688195  -908015
2019-08-03T20:00:00Z 178928226 179688195  -759969
2019-08-03T21:00:00Z 179065241 179688195  -622954
2019-08-03T22:00:00Z 179183098 179688195  -505098
2019-08-03T23:00:00Z 179306179 179688195  -382016
2019-08-04T00:00:00Z 179306179 179370042  -63863
2019-08-04T00:00:00Z 179370042 179370042  0
2019-08-04T01:00:00Z 179417649 179370042  47607
2019-08-04T02:00:00Z 179464094 179370042  94053
2019-08-04T03:00:00Z 179509960 179370042  139918
2019-08-04T04:00:00Z 179591820 179370042  221779
2019-08-04T05:00:00Z 179872817 179370042  502775
2019-08-04T06:00:00Z 180056278 179370042  686236
2019-08-04T07:00:00Z 179929713 179370042  559671
2019-08-04T08:00:00Z 179514604 179370042  144562
2019-08-04T09:00:00Z 179053049 179370042  -316992
2019-08-04T10:00:00Z 178683225 179370042  -686817
2019-08-04T11:00:00Z 178078269 179370042  -1291773
2019-08-04T12:00:00Z 177650387 179370042  -1719654
2019-08-04T13:00:00Z 177281724 179370042  -2088317
2019-08-04T14:00:00Z 177041367 179370042  -2328674
2019-08-04T15:00:00Z 176807397 179370042  -2562645
2019-08-04T16:00:00Z 176737148 179370042  -2632894
2019-08-04T17:00:00Z 176677349 179370042  -2692693
2019-08-04T18:00:00Z 176690702 179370042  -2679340
2019-08-04T19:00:00Z 176734825 179370042  -2635216
2019-08-04T20:00:00Z 176810300 179370042  -2559742
2019-08-04T21:00:00Z 176866035 179370042  -2504007
2019-08-04T22:00:00Z 176914803 179370042  -2455239
2019-08-04T23:00:00Z 176965893 179370042  -2404149
2019-08-05T00:00:00Z 176965893 177016983  -51090
2019-08-05T00:00:00Z 177016983 177016983  0
```

Example graph:

[image: Sawtooth plotting in Grafana and influxdb]